# what is the status of nosql in 2013?

Tags: nosql

My question seems to be dump, but because i was studying this new technique, i've found that NoSql has changed from its beginning, for example, in the beginning there was the problem of *see your own update*, and for example Facebook dident let users to update their comments due to the *write once, read many*

So, do i change all concepts that i've read in 2010-2012 tutorials?

Has NoSql beat the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) ?

Comment: 1.) This question is *not* a good fit for this site, as it's not concrete enough and will likely result in discussion (instead of specific answers). 2.) please don't use `code formatting` to highlight words (**bold** or *cursive* work just fine for that).

Comment: ok, sorry, i'll modify it, about the question, i just need what has changed! and it think it will be a specific answer

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There is a bunch of completely different new database technologies, and all they have in common are things they also have in common with SQL databases. You can't evaluate "NoSQL" as a whole. You have to evaluate each database technology on its own.

Comment: by putting nosql i wanted to make general name, i'm learning mongodb, and it have really changed from its first release, that's why i was asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this can easily turn into discussion.  I'll give brief answers from my experience to your two questions:

1. No, the concepts haven't changed.  The landscape seems to be growing quite a bit as lots of companies get into the NoSQL space.  Beware vendor promises!
2. No way.  Just read this article this morning, it is a great explanation on some of the issues with the CAP theorem:  http://codahale.com/you-cant-sacrifice-partition-tolerance/

Comment: thank you for the asnwer and the link,
and,sadly it was closed :(